# Is there an equivalent unicode character for the HTML horizontal rule <hr> / <hr/>

Tags: html, character, special-characters

Is there an equivalent character for the HTML horizontal rule `<hr>` or XHTML's `<hr/>` tag, that could be used outside of a browser, such as in an executable program, or the JavaScript console. I doubt there is, as we would just use the HTML entity instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&#8213` is the code for a horizontal bar, but not a horizontal line as you want. It will not be possible to create a longer or max-content line with a single Unicode character.

Comment: Well, it was worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

`&#8213;` is the HTML entry for `hr`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this: `⎯` "U+23AF Horizontal Line Extension Unicode Character".

[Source](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+23AF#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9C%E2%8E%AF%E2%80%9D%20U%2B23AF%20Horizontal%20Line%20Extension%20Unicode%20Character)

Comment: This character (&#9135;) works just great, as the character is wider than &#8213;